# IBM AIX - Method to identify Cluster or HA services

Tags: aix, cluster, high-availability

I am keen to learn if existing IBM AIX servers from different location have Clustering/HA features. Kindly let me know the steps to check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean. AIX has (from the start) *some* "cluster-features", notably "Cluster-Aware AIX" (CAA).

Then there is the classic cluster software from IBM, which is a separate product. IBM marketing regularly renames their products, so you may find information googling for "HACMP" (the original name), "SystemMirror" (later) or "PowerHA" (current). Most admins call it still "HACMP" anyway.

The easiest way to find out if HACMP is installed is to query the installed filesets:

> user@lpar:> lslpp -l cluster*

There should be - at least - some of these filesets, probably a much longer list, depending on the way the product is installed:

cluster.es.client.clcomd
cluster.es.client.lib
cluster.es.client.rte
cluster.es.client.utils
cluster.es.cspoc.cmds
cluster.es.cspoc.rte
cluster.es.server.diag
cluster.es.server.events
cluster.es.server.rte
cluster.license

If you want to know if the cluster is *working* you can use the `clstat` command:

> root@lpar:> clstat -a

This should bring up an overview of the participating nodes, which resource group is active on which node, etc..

If this fails, try:

> user@lpar:> lssrc -g cluster

The services clstrmgrES (cluster manager), clevmgrES (event manager) and clinfoES (cluster info) should be running.